# Set cursor position in a Text widget

Tags: python, tkinter, cursor-position

Is it possible to set the cursor position in a Tkinter Text widget? I'm not finding anything terribly useful yet.

The best I've been able to do is emit a `<Button-1>` and `<ButtonRelease-1>` event at a certain x-y coordinate, but that is a pixel amount, not a letter amount.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If "text", "line", and "column" are your text object, the desired text line and desired column variables are, respectively:

```
text.mark_set("insert", "%d.%d" % (line + 1, column + 1))
```

If you would not like to care about the line number... well, you have to.

Complete documentation at [The Tkinter Text Widget](https://web.archive.org/web/20200201190621/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm).

Comment: Perfect! I thought it might be somewhere along those lines but I couldn't figure it out. Is there a related method for getting the current cursor position?

Comment: @Wayne Werner: the "index" method will return the index of any position including the insertion cursor: `text.index("insert")`

Comment: `effbot.org` link has been broken for a long time now. :(

Comment: Thanks. Pointed it to the content backed up by archive.org.

Comment: lines are one-based, columns are zero-based. so, the top-left position ("home") is `1.0`

Answer (score 9):

To set the cursor position, you can use the `text_widget.mark_set` method, with `"insert"` (or `Tkinter.INSERT` for a “constant”) first argument and, for the second argument, one of many forms, the most useful being:

- `"%d,%d" % (line, column)`, where line is 1-based and column is 0-based
- `"1.0+%d chars" % index`, where index is 0-based just like a string/unicode index in Python

To get the index of a mark, you can use the `text_widget.index` method:

```
text_widget.index(Tkinter.INSERT)
```

Answer (score 2):

This property is just for Text Widget, because for Entry Widget we could use:

```
entry_widget_name.icursor("position")
```

For Text Widget will be:

```
text_widget_name.mark_set("insert", "%d.%d" % (x,y))
```

where x = row position
y = column position

(using integer numbers with dots like 1.0  or 3.0 for example)