# controlling mouse with pyusb

Tags: python, usb, mouse, pyusb

I have to make a application, that do the followings:

- disable that the given usb mouse move the pointer in the screen (just the given, not all  mouses).
- get the coordinates of the mouse pointer
- change the y coordinate of the mouse pointer

I've tried out `pyusb`, but i've never found any examples for any of the 3 problems.
Any ideas?

Comment: You should at least specify what operating system it is (I guess Linux, but you should tell us) and what environment (I guess Xorg, but you should tell).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know enough `pyusb` but you can deal with the second issue with Tkinter (one of the most used GUI with Python). Here is a sample of code (found [here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/126488)):

```
# show mouse position as mouse is moved and create a hot spot

import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def showxy(event):
    xm = event.x
    ym = event.y
    str1 = "mouse at x=%d  y=%d" % (xm, ym)
    root.title(str1)
    # switch color to red if mouse enters a set location range
    x = 100
    y = 100
    delta = 10  # range
    if abs(xm - x) < delta and abs(ym - y) < delta:
        frame.config(bg='red')
    else:
        frame.config(bg='yellow')


frame = tk.Frame(root, bg= 'yellow', width=300, height=200)
frame.bind("<Motion>", showxy)
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Yet, it seems like you cannot change the cursor position with Tkinter only (see this [thread](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/194446) for some workarounds). But if you are trying to set position within a text, you can use a widget as described in this SO thread: [Set cursor position in a Text widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215549/tkinter-set-cursor-position).

To disable mouse, you could have a look at [this post](http://idope.wordpress.com/2010/10/10/linux-disabling-touchpad-with-usb-mouse-connected/) and adapt the code to disable mouse instead of touchpad (but the post gives some interesting keys to begin with).